# "Overlaid" or "overlain" as an adjective

Tags: grammar, word-usage, past-participles

I have a set of three images, which I have put on top of each other in an image editing program and made transparent. I would like the filename to describe what I have done with the component images.

Which is the correct phrase to use for the filename in this situation: "Overlain Images" or "Overlaid Images"?

Comment: [Overlain](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overlain?q=overlain) vs [overlaid](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overlaid?q=overlaid)

Comment: A complete set of conjugates is provided here. http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/overlie.html

Comment: see also: **overlain v. overlaid** http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:overlay

Comment: *Layered images*?

Answer (score 14):

There are two different verbs at play here:

1. *[Overlie](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overlie)*; past *overlay*, past participle *overlain*.

   > 1. to lie over or upon, as a covering or stratum.
   > 2. to smother (an infant) by lying upon it, as in sleep.
2. *[Overlay](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overlay)*; past *overlaid*, past participle *overlaid*.

   > 1. to lay or place (one thing) over or upon another.
   > 2. to cover, overspread, or surmount with something.
   > 3. to finish with a layer or applied decoration of something: *wood richly overlaid with gold.*
   > 4. *Printing.* to put an overlay upon.

The meanings overlap somewhat, but while "A *overlies* B", "I *overlay* A on B". Hence it is *overlay* that is used of superimposed images. It is also *overlay* that exists as a noun for such a superimposed or covering item.

Hence, you want *overlaid*.

Better still, just use the plural noun *overlays* (all the more so, since the components are not overlaid while stored in separate files, but *overlay* the noun does include things that are intended to be overlaid, as well as things that currently are overlaid, and the term has an established use in terms of superimposed computer images).

Comment: @AndyT nice edit.